# array_push в многомерном массиве

Tags: php, foreach, циклы

Я гружу на сервер 2 картинки, а грузится только одна, потому что происходит редирект и вторая картинка является последней в массиве, а мне нужно сделать так, чтобы и 2 загрузились, и я получил редирект.
Ищу костыль для редиректа после окончания прохождения цикла. Остановился на варианте добавления значения через array_push, чтобы выполнять действие при последнем ненужном значении.
Код:

```
     foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $k=>$v)
      {
                array_push($FILES['image']['name'][$k], "apple");

    if (!next($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
             $_SESSION['success'] = "zbs!";
            header("Location: ../fund_deposit.php");}
//дальше идет много ненужного кода
```

Вроде бы все хорошо, но я получаю warning, в следствие которого мой костыль ломается напополам:

```
array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
```

Впритык не вижу ошибку.

Comment: Ещё раз: что вы пытаетесь сделать каким-то странным способом? Чтобы условие были истинно только если foreach сделал хоть одну итерацию? `$isUploadSuccess = false; foreach (/**/) { $isUploadSuccess = true; } if ($isUploadSuccess) {/**/}`

Comment: Я гружу на сервер 2 картинки, а грузится только одна, потому что происходит редирект и вторая картинка является последней в массиве, а мне нужно сделать так, чтобы и 2 загрузились, и я получил редирект.

Comment: а зачем редиректить до обработки файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка 1: `$_FILES`
Строка 3: `$FILES`